# Calling a stored procedure in ADFv2 with output (JSON) from an Azure Function call. Passing type, not JSON string?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I'm creating a pipeline in ADFv2 that calls an Azure Function that outputs JSON. I'm then passing that JSON into a stored procedure Activity, but the stored procedure isn't getting the JSON text, it's getting the object type. I've been able to pass a single JSON Value successfully.

Here are some of the attempts and their results:

```
@activity('AzureFunction').output                      - Dictionary Error
@activity('AzureFunction').output.FileList             - List Error
@activity('AzureFunction').output.fileList[0].FileName - Sent name of file (Hospital_Overview.csv)
@activity('AzureFunction').output.firstRow             - Cannot be evaluated becauase property firstRow doesn't exist
@activity('AzureFunction').output.fileList             - List Error
@activity('AzureFunction').output.production           - Sent value of production JSON node (False)
@activity('AzureFunction').output()                    - Invalid Template
@activity('AzureFunction').output.response             - activity('AzureFunction').output.response' cannot be evaluated because property 'response' doesn't exist, available properties are 'fileList, production, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, executionDuration, durationInQueue, billingReference'
@activity('AzureFunction').output.ToString()           - unable to parse
@activity('AzureFunction').output.value                - The expression 'activity('AzureFunction').output.value' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'fileList, production, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, executionDuration, durationInQueue, billingReference'
```

The JSON being sent to the stored procedure is as follows:

```
{
"fileList": [
    {
        "FileName": "File1.csv",
        "FileDate": "2019-12-13T11:26:54Z",
        "Downloaded": false,
    },
    {
        "FileName": "File2",
        "FileDate": "2019-12-13T11:29:26Z",
        "Downloaded": false,
    }
],
"production": false,
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US 2)",
"executionDuration": 6,
"durationInQueue": {
    "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
},
"billingReference": {
    "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
    "billableDuration": {
        "Managed": 0.016666666666666666
    }
}
}
```

I expected the following options to work:

```
@activity('AzureFunction').output
```

The stored procedure gives me the following error message:

> Error number: 13609. Severity: 16. State: 3. Procedure: dbo.Control_Insert_FromAzureFunction. Line: 76.
>   Message: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'S' is found at position 0..

I define the incoming JSON as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and log it so I can see what I'm getting:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]
```

So in the Azure SQL database wasn't passed text, it was passed an object. I either need to know how to convert the object in Azure SQL database to a string, or just pass the JSON text from the stored procedure activity.

This is the stored procedure I'm using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Control_Insert_FromAzureFunction] 
    @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RC INT = 0,
            @StatusMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Pending...',
            @ErrorDescription VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
            @ProcedureName VARCHAR(MAX) = object_name(@@PROCID),
            @LogId INT = 0, 
            @ProcessQueueId INT = 0;

    BEGIN TRY
        IF object_id('tempdb..#File') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #File;
        END;

        CREATE TABLE #File
        (
            [FileName]   VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL, 
            [FileDate]   DATETIME2    NOT NULL,
            [Downloaded] BIT          NOT NULL
        );

        INSERT INTO #File ([FileName], [OutputFileName], [FileDate], [Downloaded], 
                           [SFTPElapsedTime], [SFTPStartTime], [SFTPEndTime])
            SELECT 
                json_value(files.[Value], '$.FileName') AS [FileName],
                CAST(json_value(files.[Value], '$.FileDate') AS DATETIME2) AS [FileDate],
                CAST(json_value(files.[Value], '$.Downloaded') AS BIT) AS [Downloaded]
            FROM 
                OPENJSON(@json, '$.fileStatus') AS files;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @RC = -1;

        SET @StatusMessage = @json;

        EXEC [dbo].[Log_Merge] @LogId = @LogId OUT
                                    , @ProcessQueueId = @ProcessQueueId
                                    , @ProcedureName = @ProcedureName
                                    , @StatusMessage = @StatusMessage
                                    , @ErrorDescription = @ErrorDescription
                                    , @ReturnCode = @RC;
    END CATCH;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to wrap the object in the string function.  It looks like primitive types like string and int send their value, but a Dictionary sends the object type unless you specifically ask for string value.  Hopefully this helps someone else struggling with this in the future.

```
@string(activity('GetDefinitiveDataFunction').output)
```

Comment: I was struggling with this exact scenario for so long! This solved my problem.